# wxpython - Need help adjusting GUI

Tags: python, wxpython

Working on a program ([found here](http://milogert.com/gui_dnd.zip), the files are longer, so posting them here would take up much space). My problem with it is that the main panel of **gui_step_1.py** is way off center from where it should be.

I have tried numerous things, including adding it to a sizer to straighten it out, but because of my program structure (MVC) I can't do that because I instantiate `controller` in **gui_step_1.py** and `controller` does not inherit panel, frame, or anything related to wx (just a normal class).

What I need is pretty obvious once you see my program: I need `step1` (instance of `controller` in **gui_step_1.py**) centered on the window.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't sort through everything, but I think `self.v.Center()` in your `controller` class in `gui_step_1.py` is repositioning a Panel within its Frame instead of centering the Frame.  Get rid of that, and things seem to line up properly.  If you want to add the panel to a sizer, you'll probably have to retrieve it from the `controller` class.

The trouble you're having with the interface is more a symptom of a design problem, though.  Your view frame creates instances of two different classes, which create instances of widgets which are children of the frame.  Although you're trying to use MVC, it shouldn't be changing the way you add a widget to a frame.

Comment: Ok that worked well! What about that blank space then? the step1 panel is off center. Again, it would have been easier if I could have put it in a sizer. Basically what I want is it to expand out to the side to fill the whole window.

Comment: Honestly, I'd rethink the design.  As it is, what you'll have to do is reach through to get the Panel object as `self.step1.v` and add that to a sizer on the main `view` frame.  And don't forget to put the growable row/col back in its GridBagSizer so the panel can actually expand.  I can add an example to the answer if it helps, but it's just a workaround for a larger problem.

Comment: I would be up for a redesign (as I am learning as I go, so anything that might help point me in the right direction as far as good practices is ok with me) but one thing I _would_ like to keep is the MVC pattern, unless there is a better way to do it (I also like pubsub a lot, and I would like to implement that too).

But really, any suggestions are taken openly! So suggest away and if you can point me to a resource (site or book) that would help in this, let me know.

Comment: Search for the [mvc] tag here and on programmers.stackexchange.com, or start a fresh question on how to apply MVC to what you're trying to create.  It's a whole separate topic.  I added some explanation to my answer above.